# Django issue - NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, python-2.7, openstack-horizon

I'm working on extending Horizon to include a custom app.
In that app, I have a DataTable:

```
class WorkloadsTable(tables.DataTable):
    name = tables.Column("name", verbose_name=_("Name"))
    description = tables.Column("description", verbose_name=_("Description"))
    image = tables.Column("image", verbose_name=_("Image"))
    flavor = tables.Column("flavor", verbose_name=_("Flavor"))

    class Meta:
        name = "workloads_table"
        verbose_name = _("Workloads Table")
        table_actions = (CreateNewWorkload, DeleteWorkload)
        row_actions = (UpdateWorkload, DeleteWorkload)
```

which has a LinkAction:

```
class UpdateWorkload(tables.LinkAction):
    name = "update"
    verbose_name = _("Edit Workload")
    url = "horizon:mydashboard:workloads_panel:update"
    classes = ("ajax-modal",)
    icon = "pencil"

    def get_link_url(self, datum):
        base_url = super(UpdateWorkload, self).get_link_url(datum)
        workload_id = self.table.get_object_id(datum)
        reversed = urlresolvers.reverse(self.url, args=[workload_id])
        print reversed
        return urlresolvers.reverse(self.url, args=[workload_id])
```

This LinkAction points to a routce in my urls.py:

```
WORKLOADS = r'(?P<workload_id>[^/]+)/%s$'

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^create/$', views.CreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(WORKLOADS % 'update', views.UpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

The issue is:  When I enter the following url:

```
http://localhost:9000/mydashboard/workloads_panel/3/update

I get:  NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'mydashboard/workloads_panel/(?P<workload_id>[^/]+)/update$']
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't think this error can come from your example. Does your traceback tell you where it was called from? The template by any chance? Your examples all use `args=[workload_id]`. Even if it was None, you'd see it in the `NoReverseMatch` exception. Could have to do with the `tables` I am unaware of. Either way, I hope your traceback tells you where we need to be looking.

Comment: I have a gist with complete detail, including errors, and the files involved: https://gist.github.com/eugene-goldberg/8278d632760b317450b1

Comment: Your traceback suggests this is coming from the template (judging by the `reverse` call coming from `defaulttags.py`) Find where you are using the {% url %} tag incorrectly w/o arguments.

Comment: here is my template: https://gist.github.com/eugene-goldberg/0a024db8ba20c5a522bc

Comment: I'm very new to this, which part should I modify and how, please?

Comment: The exception message alone doesn't tell us enough.

In the Traceback on the error page click on 'copy and paste-view'. It contains more information about how the error happened. 

Edit your question and add the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now the answer is quite simple. There is no matching URL for this reverse call:

`{% url 'horizon:mydashboard:workloads_panel:update' %}`

The `update` named URL pattern requires a valid `workload_id` argument matching your regex `[^/]+`

Comment: being totally new to this, am I putting this ^/ in front of my url pattern in urls.py?

Comment: including this: {% block form_action %}{% url 'horizon:mydashboard:workloads_panel:update' workload_id %}{% endblock %} got rid of the error. The edit form now shows up, but the data is not passed to it. Will open a separate question. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the solution to your problem lies in the _update.html where you have to include the URL as,

```
{% block form_action %}
{% url 'horizon:mydashboard:workloads_panel:update' workload.id  %}
{% endblock %}
```

while the workload.id is the object's id that you get in views.py in get_context_data function:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(## the class name ##, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    try:
        context['workload'] = ##your API call ##(self.request,
                                                self.kwargs['id'])
    except Exception:
        exceptions.handle(self.request)
    return context
```

May be this will help you to resolve the error.